# How to take any character after period in input url pattern property?

Tags: regex, validation, url

I have a form as shown below in which URL field must start with http:// or https:// followed by at least one character.

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
  Homepage: <input type="url" id="myURL" name="website" pattern="https?://.+\." title="Include http://">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I need to make in the pattern above so that user can enter any amount of character after period (`\.`) in the URL.

Comment: `https?://.+\..*` ... but this seems like an overly-generic URL pattern.  Could you make it more specific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `.*$` to the end of your regex. This will allow the user to add zero or more characters after the dot pattern, out to the end of the string. If you'd like to prevent the user from adding more dots, you can use `[^\.\s]*$` instead.

The complete regex is `https?:\/\/.+\..*$` [(Demo)](https://regex101.com/r/yzgzP1/1/)

Comment: I want user to enter anything after period at this moment.

Comment: Looks like this should work fine in that case - it meets all your constraints.

Comment: I think there is some confusion. The URL field must start with `http://` or `https://` followed by at least `one character` and then `a period` and then `any amount of characters`.

Comment: The regex `https?:\/\/.+\..*$` addresses your requirements - `/` needs to be escaped, and a second dot is needed in your regex, since the first one just asks for unlimited periods after the end of the initial string. [(Demo)](https://regex101.com/r/yzgzP1/1/) Answer updated.

Comment: I updated your fiddle with the new regex, and it [looks to be working.](https://jsfiddle.net/donovanreed418/yvrf3z1t/)